# precision of floating point in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, precision

While working with tensorflow (version 1.4) faced some problem while debugging my code. Tensorflow have some serious precision error fault. I have shown here an example. Is there any way to handle this type of issue in tensorflow?

```
>>> a = [18.00146484]
>>> b= [[18.00146484]]
>>> c = [[[18.00146484]]]
>>> d = [[18.00146484],[12.83231735]]
>>> e = [[[18.00146484],[12.83231735]]]
>>> q = tf.nn.sigmoid()
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> q = tf.nn.sigmoid(a)
>>> w = tf.nn.sigmoid(b)
>>> e = tf.nn.sigmoid(c)
>>> r = tf.nn.sigmoid(d)
>>> z = [[[18.00146484],[12.83231735]]]
>>> t = tf.nn.sigmoid(z)
>>> init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2017-12-12 15:41:53.766287: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
>>> qq,ww,ee,rr,tt = sess.run([q,w,e,r,t])
>>> qq,ww,ee,rr,tt
(array([ 1.], dtype=float32), array([[ 1.]], dtype=float32), array([[[ 1.]]], dtype=float32), array([[ 1.        ],
       [ 0.99999738]], dtype=float32), array([[[ 1.        ],
        [ 0.99999738]]], dtype=float32))
>>> qq
array([ 1.], dtype=float32)
>>> ww
array([[ 1.]], dtype=float32)
>>> ee
array([[[ 1.]]], dtype=float32)
>>> rrr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rrr' is not defined
>>> rr
array([[ 1.        ],
       [ 0.99999738]], dtype=float32)
>>> tt
array([[[ 1.        ],
        [ 0.99999738]]], dtype=float32)
>>> from math import exp
>>> a = 18.00146484
>>> b = (1/(1+exp(-a)))
>>> b
0.9999999847923136
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, looking at how many trials you have, maybe you felt that tensorflow gives different results for the same initial value. It does not appear to be the case. `sigmoid(18.00146484)` is always 1 and `sigmoid(12.83231735)` is always 0.99999738.

Maybe you feel that `sigmoid(18.00146484)` is sufficiently far from 1 and should not be rounded to 1, but that is not the case. `sigmoid(18.00146484) = 0.99999998479231364...` (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigmoid(18.00146484)) and this number is too close to 1 for float32 precision. You really need to use a double (`tf.float64` in tensorflow) for this level of precision. Here is a simple C++ program that shows the closest representable numbers to 1 for float and double.

```
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  typedef std::numeric_limits< double > dbl;
  typedef std::numeric_limits< double > flt;

  double sigmoid = 0.99999998479231364;

  float x = 1.0;
  double firstSmallerThanX = std::nextafter(x, 0.0f);
  std::cout.precision(flt::max_digits10);
  std::cout << std::fixed << firstSmallerThanX << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Sigmoid is bigger than firstSmallerThanX: " << (sigmoid > firstSmallerThanX) << std::endl;

  double y = 1.0;
  double firstSmallerThanY = std::nextafter(y, 0.0);
  std::cout.precision(dbl::max_digits10);
  std::cout << std::fixed << firstSmallerThanY << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Sigmoid is smaller than firstSmallerThanY: " << (sigmoid < firstSmallerThanY) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This Prints:

```
0.99999994039535522
Sigmoid is bigger than firstSmallerThanX: 1
0.99999999999999989
Sigmoid is smaller than firstSmallerThanY: 1
```

Comment: yes, I understand they are closer. I have also shown them in my code at the bottom. But while you are using 1e-5 learning rate isn't 1e-8 precision contributes running thousands of batches ..?. But yes thanks for the float64 variable information.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am just that isn't 1e-8 precision matters sometimes?

Comment: I have not personally encountered the need for float64 in practice except in some unstable training cases. Such cases have other problems and high sensitivity is just a sign of them. A major feature of latest NVIDIA cards is native support for float16 - even this resolution is usually good enough in many cases. Having said that, I can certainly imagine some scientific models where ultimate precision is necessary.

Comment: Thank you @iga for sharing your idea.

Comment: This cpp example is helpful. I just came into a bug where using float instead of double will eventually cause significant different numerical outputs after a chain of operations. The root cause is exactly as shown in the example, because one of the operation is discretization.